# Running Silverlight 5 RC P/Invoke application in a browser from internet?

Tags: web, pinvoke, silverlight-5.0

Is it possible to run Silverlight 5 RC application that is using P/Invoke to access Win API functions while the application is run in web browser? The source of the application is from web site on internet.

I am asking this because I have no luck. 
I am experiencing Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Attempt by security transparent method 'xxxx' to call native code through method 'yyyyy' failed.
Methods must be security critical or security-safe-crictical to call native code.

I tried adding [SecurityCritical] attribute on the method calling the P/Invoke method but with no success. Then I tried to put it to the entire calling class but again with no luck.

Does anybody has a solution for this?

Is it possible to do that ?
Is it a problem because of the partial trust of applications from internet ?

Comment: Silverlight 5 RC? You mean Release Candidate? Or did you mean RTM/RTW?

Comment: Yes. I mean Release Candidate.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the latest version? It is possible that the RC contained significant bugs that were fixed later.

Comment: I am sorry I started with RC version and left it automatically. I moved to the latest Silverlight version but with no luck. It looks like we need special registry configuration to make a full trust application.

Comment: Ah yes, if your question was just 'how to enable elevated trust in browser', you need code signing + registry/group policy setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use P/Invoke, your SL application must be a full-trust application.

You can run trusted application from a browser, but it requires [some setup by an admin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: In the and there is no much benefit of having the possibility to run Win32 instruction with P/Invoke. The same is better achieved with standalone application then Silverlight.